# Table column one below the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to arrange the column of a `table` one below the other in a responsive view.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A...</td>
    <td>B...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
+---------+-------------+
|    A    |    **B**    |
+---------+-------------+
|    A1   |    **B1**   |
+---------+-------------+
|    A2   |    **B2**   |
+---------+-------------+
|    A... |    **B...** |
+---------+-------------+
```

to

```
+-------------+
|      A      |
+-------------+
|      A1     |
+-------------+
|      A2     |
+-------------+
|      A...   |
+-------------+
|    **B**    |
+-------------+
|    **B1**   |
+-------------+
|    **B2**   |
+-------------+
|    **B...** |
+-------------+
```

and this MUST BE A TABLE.
How can I achieve this?

How to do the media query is clear.

Also jQuery or native CSS would be fine.

Comment: And any attempts ?

Comment: `responsive view`..are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: no bootstrap in use

Comment: No this isn't what I'm searching for.COLUMN BELOW COLUMN

Comment: So you don't want to use media queries? If so when should layout break?

Comment: of course I want to use media queries but thats not the question ... the question is how to rearrange the columns when using media queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired structure by wrapping the table in a new way.

The new table-row can then be set to

> display: flex

and you can get your desired order by setting the order of every

> td:nth-child(2n)

```js
$('td').unwrap();
$('td').wrapAll('<tr></tr>');
```

```css
tr {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

td:nth-child(2n) {
order: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A...</td>
    <td>B...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice approach, but what if I've 7 cols and unknown rows? like in a week calendar? ;-)

Comment: do you mean 7 '<tr>' and unknown '<td>' ? The table-rows aren't the problem here. Atfer the wrapping all '<td>'s will be wrapped in only one '<tr>'. To get a specific order for the '<td>'s you will need classes. Then you will be able to set the 'order' for each class.

Comment: no 7 <td> and unknown <tr> i've not the possibility to set a class

Comment: Ok, please consider to write such info into the question the next time. But for your question asked this is the right answer

Comment: yes you're right. could you please give an example for the wanted 7 days <td> and unknown rows?

Answer (score 3):

Making `td` as `display:block` would work but not row wise.

```css
td{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<table border=1 cellpadding=6 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah not row wise ;-)
This isn't the structure I want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This isn't the structure I want to achieve!

Comment: so what is your desired structure?

Comment: perhaps you should hava a look at the initial post! :-/

Comment: ok, I see now. Well, you need javascript here... no way to place righten columns under the leften columns only with css. maybe it would work woth position: absolute and fixed height/width, but it's not a solution.

Comment: if you have a solution with javascript I would like to know. In final I need to rearrage a week calendar (7 cols and x(unknown) rows)

Answer (score 0):

jerry-rig

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
tr{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
table{
  display: flex:
  flex-direction: column;
}
td{
  border: 1px
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $fline = $('table tr td:first-child');
  $sline = $('table tr td:last-child');

  $('table').html('<tr></tr><tr></tr>');
  $fline.each(function(){
    $('table tr:first-child').append($(this));
  });
  $sline.each(function(){
    $('table tr:last-child').append($(this));
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, just, you can change ":first-child" for ":nth-of-type" and generate de "tr" inside the table based on that, but you will need to now how many rows it has

Comment: wait, i'll make an alteration

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do this. You will need to use `media queries` to change layout to flex and change order of `td`'s and also jquery to wrap/unwrap `td` elements from `tr`.

It will change when window width is < 480px.

```js
var html = $('tbody').html();
var c = false;

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    if (c == false) {
      $('td').unwrap()
      c = true;
    }
  } else {
    $('tbody').html(html)
    c = false;
  }
}).resize();
```

```css
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  td:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```